# FileSystemRights ToString formatting

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, posix

I'm enumerating files/folder with C# and wondering whether there's any libraries (or better  .Net feature) available formatting the [FileSystemAccessRule.FileSystemRights](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.accesscontrol.filesystemaccessrule.filesystemrights%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) property into a POSIX like unix file permission string;

> d--x-

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you want an encoded string when you can print out the actual string descriptions?

```
FileSystemRights Rights = 0;

Rights |= FileSystemRights.CreateFiles;
Rights |= FileSystemRights.ExecuteFile;

Console.WriteLine(Rights.ToString());

// Prints:   CreateFiles, ExecuteFile
```